# Customizing QPrintPreviewDialog with pyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

Based on the answer of [Question with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856311/customizing-qprintpreviewdialog....), I'm trying to do similar with PyQt5. I want to remove some buttons of `QPrintPreviewDialog` and add new ones. I can get the toolbar by `toolbar = dialog.findChildren(QToolBar)` and the buttons by `buttons = dialog.findChildren(QToolButton)`, where `dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)`, then I make a loop tor the buttons to check its names.

**code snipped:**

```
    dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)
    buttons = dialog.findChildren(QToolButton)
    actions = dialog.findChildren(QAction)
    toolbar = dialog.findChildren(QToolBar)
    toolbar[0].addAction("PDF", saveaspdf)           # This works fine to add a button
                                                     # and connection to saveaspdf()
    for button in buttons:
        print("entry:", button.objectName(), button.text())
        if button.text() == 'Portrait' or button.text() == 'Landscape':
            button.setDisabled(True)  # Button will be disabled
            button.setVisible(False)  # Button still visible, but disabled

     dialog.paintRequested.connect
```

I tried something with `toolbar.removeAction()`but I found no way to identify the demanded action. Also I don't think that's the solution. Also any `.removeWidget(button)` doesn't solve the problem.

So, please can you explain me this line from the mentioned page of c++ and give me a hint for PyQt:
`//toolbarlist.first()->removeAction(toolbarlist.first()->actions().at(3));`

Comment: What button do you want to remove?

Comment: Most actions in the print preview dialog have an object name, as most objects in prebuilt dialogs and complex widgets. If the action has an object name, you can use `dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QAction, 'nameOfAction')` to access the action name and then remove that action. [See the source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/printsupport/dialogs/qprintpreviewdialog.cpp.html) and look for all `setObjectName` of actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove the `Portrait` and `Landscape` buttons then you must search through the QAction text and remove it from the QToolBar.

```py
toolbar = dialog.findChild(QToolBar)
ACTIONS_TEXT = [
    QCoreApplication.translate("QPrintPreviewDialog", text)
    for text in ("Portrait", "Landscape")
]
for action in toolbar.actions():
    if action.text() in ACTIONS_TEXT:
        toolbar.removeAction(action)
```

Comment: Aaah, I've tried with the `button.text()` and never thought that `action` has the same. A little confusing, but thanks a lot.

Comment: Uhm, this won't work well with localization: on my computer, those actions are translated to "Verticale" and "Orizzontale", respectively.

Comment: @musicamante Good observation, now try my new code.